# How to declare default searchable activity

Tags: android

I am trying to implement search in my application.

My application contain 4 activities and I want to add the search dialog only on 3 of them while only one of them (ProductsActivity) will be the default context.

unfortunately while I activate the search I keep getting the following error:
"Key android.app.default_searchable expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value  was returned."

```
 <activity android:label="@string/app_name" class=".AppEntry" android:name=".AppEntry">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity android:name=".category.CategoriesListActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
 </activity>
 <activity android:name=".product.ProductsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For default searchable activity you have to put the **meta-data tag under the application tag**.

```
<application ... >  
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" 
    android:value=".DefaultSearchActivity"/>

<activity android:name=".ProductActivity" >
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" 
        android:value=".SearchActivityForProducts"/>
</activity>
...
```

In that example the default application search will be done on the **DefaultSearchActivity**, while in the *ProductActivity* the search will be on **SearchActivityForProducts**. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: but it is not enough with <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" 
    android:value=".product.ProductsActivity"/>
```

instead of passing the @xml reference there again.

Comment: i don't think since without the @xml reference the system default search will be the system context

Comment: Have you tried or you're guessing? All the samples i.e. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html or http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Wiktionary/AndroidManifest.html use the syntax I mentioned, with android:value and not android:resource passed. I'm only talking about the android.app.default_searchable here, not the android.app.searchable.

Comment: OK i found what was wrong - I should declare in CategoriesListActivity activity that the default search is the ProductsActivity

Comment: <activity android:name=".category.CategoriesListActivity">
         <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" 
              android:value=".product.ProductsActivity"/>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name=".product.ProductsActivity">
   <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
         </intent-filter>
         <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" 
                 android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
  </activity>

Answer (score 0):

One thing really important here is to correctly name your activities as the Android guidelines explains http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm

> android:name The name of the class that implements the activity, a
>   subclass of Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified
>   class name (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity").
>   However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a
>   period (for example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to
>   the package name specified in the  element. Once you publish
>   your application, you should not change this name (unless you've set
>   android:exported="false").
>
> There is no default. The name must be specified.

If you don't put the DOT in your activity name, your search action will only work on the activity you declared as "default_searchable". This little DOT cost us hours so be careful!